# Storyboard a push seque from a View Controller to a Navigation Controller and retain the UITabBar to the segued Navigation Controller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, navigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following Storyboard:

I dont have enough rep points yet for images :( so I posted it here:

http://www.bodharr.com/brionh/example.png

I have the following code in my Journal ViewController Class:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DiaJournals"])
    {
        UINavigationController *controller =segue.destinationViewController;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

When I push to my navigation controller the tab bar menu disappears but the table view comes up with all my data.  How do I properly segue to maintain the tab bar menu from my Journals ViewController to my Navigation Controller?

I know this is a total noobie question and I honestly have done lots of research on storyboarding and seques but other then here: [How within a tab bar controller do I segue from one view controller to another and retain the tab bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694724/how-within-a-tab-bar-controller-do-i-segue-from-one-view-controller-to-another-a) and honestly been trying to fit that into my situation, but I am just so lost and frustrated on this.  Any Help appreciated and I always mark answers.

Comment: it seems not necessary: [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: what's the style of the segue with identifier "DiaJournals"? Is it modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wire your  `Journal ViewController` directly to your `table view controller`, and set the segue style to push. Then the tab bar will maintain there when the tableview been pushed. In your storyboard the navigation controller is modaled by the `Journal ViewController` , so the tab bar will disappear.

Comment: Style is set to push, but i see your point with the presentModalViewController (and I should have gotten that from the last example i looked at, doh) what should I replace that line with?

Comment: @BriOnH Just comment it. But I find in your .png that the style of the segue with identifier "DiaJournals" is modal. ps. Navigation view controller cant not be pushed.

Comment: @BriOnH Why not embeded your Journal ViewController in a Navigation controller?

Comment: @luyaun - I embedded it and it worked! Thank you!! Wish I had the points to vote you up.  Thank you!!!