# tab bar disppears in view from another controller ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have two controllers . A HomeVC and a UITabBar VC with 5 tabs. Each Tab has a view associated with it added in storyboard. Default landing page for the application is the view related to first tab. In each of the five tab views , there is a button named "menu" which takes me to the view related to HomeVC. Now, the problem is , when I press menu button and go to HomeVC's view, the tab bar does not appear. Is there a way to retain the tab bar in my Home VC's view with no tab selected?

Comment: I predict that you are using segues to go "back" to the home VC right? Can you show a screenshot of your storyboard.

Comment: no..i am using the storyboard id..like...                                HomeViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: OK, same thing. Can you show the storyboard anyway just so I can get an idea of what's going on.

Comment: I need 10 reputation to attach an image..I just added the tabs by dragging the tabbar controller to the required view controller and selecting the option view controller..like.."Relationship view controller to view x"

Comment: Can you not just put a link to a photo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694724/how-within-a-tab-bar-controller-do-i-segue-from-one-view-controller-to-another-a?rq=1     I am stuck with same problem

Answer (score 0):

You just have to embed your `UITabBar ViewController` in a `Navigation Controller`.

Comment: @mahivamsi Yes. Did you try?

Comment: I tried..but i could not find the option to embed UITabBar ViewController in a Navigation Controller.

Comment: @mahivamsi Not the UITabBar ViewController. You should embed your View Controllers which have been attached to a UITabBar. :)

Comment: I have already done that..my problem is similar to this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694724/how-within-a-tab-bar-controller-do-i-segue-from-one-view-controller-to-another-a?rq=1....any help please!!

Comment: Can you send me the source code so that I can take a look?